# PHP - Cannot get telephonenumber from LDAP when multiple entries

Tags: php, ldap

When I query AD using LDAP I get all entries I want except for the telephone number. When I include telephonenumber, when retrieving more than 1 entry from AD I get:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: telephonenumber in C:\inetput\wwwroot\foo\query.php on line 36

When I search for 1 single user, I get the phone number, any suggestions?

```
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {
echo "Common Name:" . $data[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
echo "Distinguished Name:" . $data[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
echo "Telephone Number:" . $data[$i]["telephonenumber"][0] . "<br /><hr />"; }
ldap_close($ds);
```

Comment: Are you sure other entries has telephone number?

Comment: yes, they are set on all entries I query

Comment: try print_r($data[$i]["telephonenumber"]);

Comment: What does your filter look like? If you want to be sure everything you query has a telephone number you should add `(telephonenumber=*)`

Comment: Thanks ChadSikorra. At first it seems to have solved my issue but then I tried to get the location "l" and I get the same error as I had with the telephonenumber. Now it seems that when my filter has two or more conditions (doesn't matter which) `$filter = "(|(cn=*)(telephonenumber=*))"` I get telephonenumber but not location, when my filter only has one condition `$filter = "cn=*"` I get neither...